# Un jComboBox a un item.getText() Java NetBeans para INSERT mysql

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8.1

estoy precisando obtener un string de un jComboBox en el cual utilizo para que el usuario elija una provincia.
El jComboBox lo nombre **(jComboProvincias)** y cree un string de la siguiente manera:

```
private void jComboProvinciasActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
provincia=(String)jComboProvincias.getSelectedItem().toString();
}
```

Y en el insert cuando quiero agregarlo me sale el siguiente error:

```
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO clientes VALUES(NULL,'" + tfNotas.getText() + "','" + jComboProvincias.getText() + "')");
```

Pero en la linea me da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues la forma de obtener un item y covertirlo a String del JComboBox es como lo haces al principio: `jComboProvincias.getSelectedItem().toString();`, pero en tu INSERT ya lo haces diferente, ahí el problema.

Comment: Hola Oscar G, cual seria el probema del INSERT? porque anteriormente viene trabajando sin problemas, y solo da el fallo cuando quiero insertar el jComboBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te decía en el comentario, tu error está en jComboProvincias.getText(), esa no es la forma de obtener un item del JComboBox y pasarlo a String, lo que debes de hacer es lo siguiente

```
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO clientes VALUES(NULL,'" + tfNotas.getText() + "','" + jComboProvincias.getSelectedItem().toString() + "')");
```

Comment: Hola @Oscar G muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me funciono correctamente con lo que me planteaste, gracias totales.

Answer (score 1):

Al ser un Jcombobox en vez de pone `getText()` tienes que poner lo siguiente:

```
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO clientes VALUES(NULL,'" + tfNotas.getText() + "','" + jComboProvincias.getSelectedItem().toString() + "')");
```

Aquí te dejo un enlace de una pagina la cual da un ejemplo muy claro sobre el tema: https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/javaya/detalleconcepto.php?codigo=109&punto=&inicio=

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: No hay de que amigo!

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el texto del elemento seleccionado en el `JComboBox` debes usar [getSelectedItem()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem--), de esta forma

```
String valor = (String)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
```